# Math samples in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there a package (or other 'native' solution) to generate a 'table of contents' of formulas?

I am collecting integrals for an 'integral dictionary' and for each integral I have the 'blocks'

- Integral
- Hint
- Answer
- Solution

The 'Integral' block is on the form

```
Show that
[\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\arctan x+C]
```

and I would like to generate a table of contents with

```
[\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx] .... 'page number'
```

etc. Note that the part to the right of `=` is not included.
If this parsing is difficult I could write a double entry in the code, like

```
Show that
[\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\arctan x+C]
```

Send to toc:

```
[\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx]
```

Is this something that has been done and is there a package for this?

There is no 'must' to use the 'normal' table of contents, a 'special' formula table of contents will work as good, or even better, to be able to have both in the same document.

TIA

Comment: You could define the necessary macros yourself, but there is no ready-to-use solution to my knowledge. You should be able to find information on how to set up a new kind of ToC on this site (or the internet in general).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very basic setup doing a minimum of formatting:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlistof{integral}{int}{List of Integrals}

\newcommand\newintegral[2]
  {%
    \refstepcounter{integral}%
    Show that
    \[ #1=#2 \tag{\theintegral} \]%
    \addcontentsline{int}{integral}{\protect\numberline{\theintegral}$#1$}%
  }

\begin{document}
\listofintegral

\section{Integrals}
\newintegral{\int x\,\mathrm{d}x}{\frac{1}{2}x^2+C}
\newintegral{\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x}{\arctan x+C}
\end{document}
```

[image]